# mysql: selecting persons who have a certain amount of relational rows

Tags: mysql, in-clause, having-clause

I have two relational tables, person and event_registration, and I would like to select all persons who have registered to 10 or less events. I have found a query which seems to be correct. It can find these persons with the following query:

```
  SELECT person_id 
    FROM event_registration 
GROUP BY person_id 
  HAVING COUNT(*) <= 10
```

Note, event_registration.person_id is related to the table row that matches person.id. Now I would like to use this query searching the person table, but my query seems to crash mysql. Why?

```
SELECT id 
  FROM person 
 WHERE id IN (
       SELECT person_id 
         FROM event_registration 
     GROUP BY person_id 
       HAVING COUNT(*) <= 10
 )
```

The reason I would like to change the query is because I also look for other properties, so the (more close to) final query will look something like:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM person 
 WHERE name LIKE '%something%' 
   AND AGE > 20 
   AND id IN (
       SELECT person_id 
         FROM event_registration 
     GROUP BY person_id 
       HAVING COUNT(*) <= 10
 )
```

Of course this doesn't work, as mysql seems to crash. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by it 'crashes mysql'?  Does the query timeout?

Comment: Yes the query times out making the web server (IIS 7) not respond any more until I restart it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct id FROM person 
WHERE id IN
    (SELECT person_id 
     FROM event_registration 
     GROUP BY person_id HAVING COUNT(*) <= 10)
```

Comment: Then the `distinct`, to do the counts just once for each distinct person, probably made the difference.

Comment: I don't understand however, that finding the IDs without a subquery would take a second, but then displaying the values along with other values would make the query take over 2 minutes...